# Factory Girl / Rails: Generator to create a factory for existing model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am using the `rspec_rails` and `factory_girl_rails` gems within my Rails project.  All of the models are already created.  Is there a generator that I can run that will create the factory file for an existing model?

Ex:  I already have a `Blog` model. RSpec allows me to generator a model spec file at `spec/models/blog_spec.rb` by simply running the following:

```
rails generate rspec:model blog
```

Is there a generator that I can run in the command line that will generate the factory file for this existing model, located at: `spec/factories/blogs.rb`?

I did not see any mentions of generators within the [factory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) docs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First configure Factory Bot.

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot, dir: "spec/factories"
end
```

Then run the generator.

```
rails g factory_bot:model Blog name description total_visits:integer
```

Comment: FactoryGirl became FactoryBot. So it is now `rails g factory_bot:model Blog`.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

**Factory Girl** has been renamed as **Factory Bot**

1. Make sure to add `factory_bot_rails` gem in `development` & `test` group
2. Then run `rails g factory_bot:model Blog name description total_visits:integer`

Example:

```rb
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end
```